# How to to use subdirectory as root in Apache 2.4

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, request, http-post, virtualhost

I'm trying to setup Apache 2.4 to use subdirectory as a root.
I would like to use http://myapp.test/test as a main url
I added the following lines to the httpd.conf file of Apache:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myapp.test
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/webapp/web/"
    Alias "/test" "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/webapp/web/"

    <Directory "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/webapp/web/">
        # use mod_rewrite for pretty URL support
        RewriteEngine on        
        RewriteBase /
        RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
        # If a directory or a file exists, use the request directly
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        # Otherwise forward the request to index.php
        RewriteRule . index.php

        # use index.php as index file
        DirectoryIndex index.php

        # ...other settings...
        # Apache 2.4
        Require all granted
            
        ## Apache 2.2
        # Order allow,deny
        # Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I tried to use

```
Alias "/test" "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/webapp/web/"
```

and

```
#RewriteRule ^test/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

but it doesn’t seem to work with POST request.

Comment: So you want `example.com/test/something` to return the same as `example.com/something`?!

Comment: I want pass from example.com to example.com/test